# Unit test for Server sent event client, Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, webclient, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I need to write unit test for this method:

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
 
 @Service
public class ConsumeDataServiceImpl implements ConsumeDataService {
public void consumeServerSentEvent(String baseUrl) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(baseUrl);
        ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type
                = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};

        Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
                .uri("/")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(type);

        eventStream.subscribe(
                content -> System.out.println("***received***"),
                error -> System.out.println("***error*** " + error),
                () -> System.out.println("***completed***"));
    }
}
```

My unit test is like this:

```
 @Test
    public void testConsumeServerSentEvent()  {
        MockWebServer mockBackEnd = new MockWebServer();
        try {
            mockBackEnd.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error in start mockbackend");
        }
        mockBackEnd.enqueue(
                new MockResponse()
                        .setResponseCode(200)
                        //.setHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream")
                        .setBody(Flux.just("Spring MVC","Spring Boot","Spring Web").toString())
        );
        Environment env = Mockito.mock(Environment.class);
        MyRepository repo = Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
        ConsumeDataServiceImpl consumeService = new ConsumeDataServiceImpl(env,repo);
        consumeService.consumeServerSentEvent(mockBackEnd.url("/").toString());
    }
```

But when i run unit test then in eventStream.subscribe in the method i receive error: Java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task

Comment: you add a `/` at the end of the `baseUrl` (`mockBackEnd.url("/")`) but then you call `uri("/stream-sse")` -- your final URL will be `backend//stream-sse`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Thanks, i updated the url and here also i updated my question, but when i run my unit test, in eventStram.subscribe it print  "***error***", so it could not receive the message

Comment: Could you print the `error` instead and add the log to your question

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Thanks, this error is printed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To test this situation first you need to create an endpoint which emits the Server Sent Event (SSE) which will be consumed by the test.

If you are using Spring boot, it is quite easy. Perform the below steps to test:

1. Create an endpoint in test package by using controller

```
    @GetMapping(produces = [ MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE ])
    fun findStandardEvents(
            @RequestParam( value = "events", required = false, defaultValue = "10") events: Int,
            @RequestParam( value = "delay", required = false, defaultValue = "1000") delay: Long
    ): Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> {
        logger.debug("streamEvent - Request received for event")
        return Flux.range(1, if(events < 1) 10 else events)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(if(delay < 1) 1000 else delay))
                .doOnNext { logger.debug("streamEvent - Event number generated $it") }
                .map {
                    val eventType = getEventType(it)
                   ServerSentEvent.builder<String>()
                            .id(it.toString())
                            .event(eventType)
                            .data("data")
                            .build()

                }
                .doOnSubscribe { logger.debug("streamEvent - Event subscribed") }
    }
```

Since, this endpoint is in test so it will not be part of delivery and used only for testing of service method.

2. To test it better split the service method in two part, first will return Flux<ServerSentEvent>

```
ConsumeDataServiceImpl consumeService = new ConsumeDataServiceImpl(env,repo);
Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> testResult = consumeService.consumeServerSentEvent("/");
```

3. Write step verifier in test as step verifier provides rich set of methods for SSE testing and assertion.

```
        StepVerifier
                .create(testResult.map { it.id() })
                .expectSubscription()
                .expectNext("1", "2", "3")
                .verifyComplete()
```

Comment: Is there any way to check for other sse message attributes? i.e. id, event or comment?

Comment: Yes! Here the code is just mapping the sse response dto to id only `it.id()`, you can get complete dto and then in expectNext method you can provide your lambda function which can verify different fields e.g. event or data.

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that there is testResult.map(it.id()). Like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77314374/11152683 I need to use "body to flux" with **ServerSentEvent** type, to get also id, comment and event fields of sse message.