# Retrieve id and event values from sse message using webClient

Tags: webclient

I have a webclient instance connected to SSE (server sent events) endpoint. I am receiving values correctly, but I miss info about message id and event type.

My server side code for sse endpoint:

```java
  @RequestMapping(path = "/sseEndpoint", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Flux<ServerSentEvent<MyInterfaceForThreeDifferentTypes>> sseEndpoint() {
    final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    return service.listenToEvents()
        .map(data -> ServerSentEvent.<MyInterfaceForThreeDifferentTypes>builder()
            // here I save id for each emitted sse message and I would like to receive it in webClient
            .id(String.valueOf(counter.incrementAndGet()))
            // here I set class name as event type (can be used for deserialization)
            .event(data.getClass().getSimpleName())
            // actual data; will be encoded as json
            .data(data)
            .build()
  }
```

Now I am consuming this endpoint in another code/service/test like this:

```java
    final WebClient wc = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.sk/")
        .build();
    wc.get().uri("sseEndpoint")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class)
        .subscribe(data -> {
            // I would like to have id and event type here also! Or better make object mapper to deserialize data according event value
            System.out.println(data);
        });
```

By using what approach it is possible to have event value used to deserialize data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my Kotlin version that worked for me:

```
client.get().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer ${readUsers().first().token}")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(ServerSentEvent::class.java)
    .subscribe { event ->
        println("flux subscribe: ${event.event()}")
    }
```

so basically in .bodyToFlux use **ServerSentEvent.class** instead of **String.class**, and then on subscribe you can get event name in example with **data.event()**

(org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEvent)

Hope this helps!